# Controlling Checkboxes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am attempting to add a No Preference choice to my check box list and what I would like to happen is as follows:

1. All checkboxes that are selected become unchecked when "No Preference" is selected.
2. If "No Preference" is selected and another checkbox is selected, then "No Prefernece" becomes unselected.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/VuS5R/1/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think that you can't use number as id, and id must be uniqe.

Comment: Just found [this](http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/javascript/checkboxes.asp). It seems like what you're looking for, with buttons instead of checkboxes. Make the `No preference` one name and the others another. The unchecking of the others would just require their name, and unchecking `No preference` would require its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elegant solution from jQuery.
The "No preference" has "Nop" class, others "pref":

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $(".Nop").click(function()
   {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
             $(".pref").attr("checked", false);      
        }
    });
    $(".pref").click(function()
    {
          if ($(this).is(":checked"))
          {
               $(".Nop").attr("checked", false);      
          }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to put an ID on the `ul` element. Then you can use `getElementByID` and `getElementsByTagName` to identify the checkboxes. Since the "No preferences" checkbox is the first, bind an event on its click to uncheck all the checkboxes if it is checked.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('input');
checkboxes[0].onclick = function(){
    if(checkboxes[0].checked){
        for(var i = 1; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjwy7/).

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you have to give each checkbox a **unique** ID (currently they all have an ID=1).
2. Then, you would change your "No Preference" checkbox declaration to this:

   input type="checkbox" id="0" name="BT" title="No Preference" value="0" checked="checked" **onclick="return NoPreference_ClientClick()"**
3. You will add the following JavaScript to your page:

   function NoPreference_ClientClick()
   {
      if ($get("0").checked)
      {
         $get("1").checked = 
         $get("2").checked = 
         $get("3").checked = 
         $get("4").checked = 
         $get("5").checked = false;
      }
      else
      {
         $get("1").checked = 
         $get("2").checked = 
         $get("3").checked = 
         $get("4").checked = 
         $get("5").checked = true;
      }
      return false;
   }

...I hope you get the pattern!

Comment: I kind of get it, still trying to figure it out this way.